# mongodb aggregation lookup with conditions in reference table

Tags: mongodb, lookup

i had try to lookup value from a table and another table in mongodb but i don't get my expected output

[I have author table with some my fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Yql.png)
[I have document table with array author_id field contain value reference to author.id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB2k1.png)

```
db.documents.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                    from: "author",
                    localField: "author_id",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "author",
            }
        },
        {
            $project : {
                author_id: 0
            }
        },
        {
            $skip: 0
        },
        {
            $limit: 2
        }
    ]
)
```

This my code to combine 2 table to get data

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "63fd8a80ae2c18ab3b81a4b1"},
    "author": [
      {
        "_id": {"$oid": "63fd80b2381bff5ebf42cd61"},
        "first_name": "Junior",
        "last_name": "Neymar",
        "address": "Brazil",
        "is_deleted": false
      },
      {
        "_id": {"$oid": "63fd812787493aea44d4af48"},
        "first_name": "cristiano",
        "last_name": "Ronaldo",
        "address": "Protugal",
        "is_deleted": true
      }
    ],
    "language": "Brazil",
    "pages": 200,
    "title": "Document 3"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "63fd8a96ae2c18ab3b81a4b2"},
    "author": [],
    "language": "Brazil",
    "pages": 200,
    "title": "Document 2"
  }
]
```

And I get this output but i don't want to get authors who have is_deleted field is true in my output
Please help me!

Comment: did you mean that you are tryng to do `lookup` from `lookup`?

Comment: i made an library to handle pagination using mongodb native drive, please take a look here [mongo-pagination](https://github.com/mrbontor/mongo-pagination), i think that is what your are looking for.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection

Answer (score 0):

you can use [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to make it easier to filter the data

```
db.documents.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "author",
      localField: "author_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "author_id",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$author_id"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "author_id.is_deleted": false
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      author_id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_0gCoULsNyL)

or you can use pipeline instead to do filter

```
db.documents.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "author",
      localField: "author_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "is_deleted": false
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "author_id",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$author_id"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      author_id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NsIo8y-xl4s)